# How to use NpgsqlCopyIn with NpgsqlCopySerializer?

Tags: c#, postgresql, npgsql

If I understand correctly NpgsqlCopyIn with NpgsqlCopySerializer should work something like this:

```
var conn = new NpgsqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["PostgreSqlDb"].ConnectionString);
conn.Open();
var tran = conn.BeginTransaction();
var cmd = new NpgsqlCommand("COPY address (id, employee, value) FROM STDIN", conn);
var npgsqlCopySerializer = new NpgsqlCopySerializer(conn);
var npgsqlCopyIn = new NpgsqlCopyIn(cmd, conn, npgsqlCopySerializer.ToStream);

try
{
    npgsqlCopyIn.Start();
    npgsqlCopySerializer.AddInt32(300);
    npgsqlCopySerializer.AddInt32(1);
    npgsqlCopySerializer.AddString("address");
    npgsqlCopySerializer.EndRow();
    npgsqlCopySerializer.Flush();
    npgsqlCopySerializer.AddInt32(301);
    npgsqlCopySerializer.AddInt32(1);
    npgsqlCopySerializer.AddString("another\r\naddress");
    npgsqlCopySerializer.EndRow();
    npgsqlCopySerializer.Flush();
    npgsqlCopyIn.End();

    tran.Commit();
}
//catch (Exception e)
//{
//    tran.Rollback();
//    throw;
//}
finally
{
    conn.Close();
}
```

Problem is that each time there are not allowed characters in `AddString()` it throws an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` inside that method, otherwise it works.

For example:

```
npgsqlCopySerializer.AddString("another\r\naddress");
```

will throw the exception cause it contains a newline which has a special meaning in [copy from text format](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/interactive/sql-copy.html) (row separator) and should be escaped.

Anyone know what I can do to make it work? I searched for examples on the internet but I couldn't find anything.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm the person who reported the bug, coincidentally only a few days ago.

Would you mind posting the XML you're trying to insert? I have tried it with an OSM result:
http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search.php?q=A7&viewbox=3.96%2C52.82%2C7.93%2C51.11&format=xml

And a rather large web.config file, both work flawlessly. So either I made a copy / paste error while submitting my fix, or the XML you're trying to insert is different than the XML I tried.

Also: do you get the exact same error as before (i.e., argument out of range)? The default buffer size is only 8k, which wasn't enough in my case.

I don't know if it makes any difference, but I didn't use flush at all:

```
NpgsqlConnection Conn = new NpgsqlConnection(getPostgresConnString());
Conn.Open();
NpgsqlCopyIn copyIn = new NpgsqlCopyIn("COPY table  (col1,col2,col2)   FROM STDIN;", Conn);
copyIn.Start();
NpgsqlCopySerializer cs1 = new NpgsqlCopySerializer(pConn2);
cs1.AddString(System.IO.File.ReadAllText("C:\\test\\Web.config"));
[...]
cs1.EndRow();
cs1.Close();
copyIn.End();
```

Comment: After applying the patch, the exception with the XML was Buffer size related as you said. I set an appropriate buffer size and it works. Thanks!

Comment: Just committed the Jelmer's patch to cvs. Thanks for your patch, Jelmer and thanks Răzvan for your testing and feedback.

Comment: What is `pConn2`?  Is it necessary to be different than `Conn`?

Comment: @brianestey I believe that was a typo, in this case. Although there was a situation where a connection with an open recordset didn't allow a second query to be fired. Just not sure if that applied here, sorry.

Comment: @Jelmer Thanks.  I actually tried the code without a second connection and it seemed to work... you have me worried about other cases now, but this case seemed to work =)

Answer (score 2):

To quote from the [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/interactive/sql-copy.html):

> It is strongly recommended that applications generating COPY data convert data newlines and carriage returns to the \n and \r sequences respectively. At present it is possible to represent a data carriage return by a backslash and carriage return, and to represent a data newline by a backslash and newline.

So I would say the following will work:

```
npgsqlCopySerializer.AddString("another\\\r\\\naddress");
```

**EDIT**: I tried it for myself and there seems to be a bug in `NpgsqlCopySerializer.AddString()`:

```
if (escapeAt > bufferedUpto)
{
    int encodedLength = ENCODING_UTF8.GetByteCount(fieldValue.ToCharArray(bufferedUpto, escapeAt));
    MakeRoomForBytes(encodedLength);
    _sendBufferAt += ENCODING_UTF8.GetBytes(fieldValue, bufferedUpto, escapeAt, _sendBuffer, _sendBufferAt);
    bufferedUpto = escapeAt;
}
```

The second line throws the `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` after the two escape sequences (`\r` and `\n`) are processed and added to the output buffer, since at that moment `bufferedUpto == 9` and `escapeAt == "another\r\naddress".Length == 16`

Now I even found [this bug](http://pgfoundry.org/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=1011215&group_id=1000140&atid=590) reported at the Npgsql tracker.

Comment: I have tried any number of backslashes between 1 and 4 and in all cases `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` was thrown.

Comment: I applied the patch specified in the bug report and it worked with `\r\n` and other simple test but it still crashed when the data string was xml. Anyway +1 for your effort :)

Comment: Hi, Razvan. Would you mind to add your feedback to the bug report on npgsql project page? This will help twoflower and others to make more tests about this problem and result in a patch which fix this problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @FranciscoJunior: The exception thrown was "IndexOutOfRangeException" inside NpgsqlCopySerializer Buffer setter. It seems the exception wasn't cause of the content type (xml), it was cause of the size of the AddString data. The xml field I was adding had around 70KB and default buffer was 8KB. I set npgsqlCopySerializer.BufferSize to a high enough value and now it works.