# C# programming to update data in database(pg admin) from a text file daily at some particular timing?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, postgresql, pgadmin

I have around 15 different text files which contain some data. The data in these files get updated each  day with few new rows in the same files.

I need to read data from these files n update this data in my database daily.So that i can read this data from my database and add it with the rest of the data to generate a crystal report file after manipulation of each days data.

What i have done till now is --

I have Created a table in my database with the same no. of variables.
then copied this data from the file and changed the format of the data too to the format required.

But i have done it manually by firing a query in Pgadmin.

Is it possible to make a program in C# which will update the table in the database for me automatically each day with the updated values from the text files ???

Comment: Look into nPgSQL's `NpgsqlCopyIn`

Comment: how your generating those `15 different text files` files ??

Comment: you can refer [this](http://devcrackers.blogspot.in/2013/06/npgsqlcopyin-and-npgsqlcopyserializer.html) or [this](http://npgsql.projects.pgfoundry.org/docs/api/Npgsql.NpgsqlCopyIn.html) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11824967/how-to-use-npgsqlcopyin-with-npgsqlcopyserializer)

Comment: @dude those files are generated by a software n get updated each day on the same path